# How to have 3 or more handles with Dojo Range Slider

Tags: javascript, dojo

With [Dojo Range Slider](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/form/RangeSlider.html) there are only two handles (Which basically serves the purpose of specifying a range).

It would be better if we have a range slider with more than two handles. In the simplest case it can be assumed that the first handle, second handle, third handle and so on represent some percentage of the whole length of the slider and they together make up 100%, like this

[image]

So, my question - is there any way to somehow do this with dojo slider, or what needs to change in the rangeSlider.js (dojox.form.RangeSlider.js) or some other file to acheive this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can relatively easily build such a widget using the Dojo dgauges framework (dojox/dgauges).  This allows you among other things to build interactive gauges with several indicator. Each vertical bar in your example would be an indicator.

See here for doc: 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/dgauges.html

Some examples:
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/dgauges/tests/test_BulletGraph.html
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/dgauges/tests/test_Classic_HorizontalLinearGauge.html

Comment: Christophe - Thanks a LOT!